# Adding Appendix and changing appendix title settings (book style)

Tags: chapters, appendices

I am adding an appendix to my book file.

But the book template for the Appendix title looks like this

[image]

but I want something like this

[image]

How do I change it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,Bold,a4paper,TexShade,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page,title,header]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\chapter[Conclusions, contributions to original knowledge and future work]{\LARGE{Conclusions, contributions to original knowledge and future work}}
\chaptermark{Conclusions, contributions to knowledge and future work}
        \input{Sections/Conclusions}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter*{Appendix A: Exploratory investigation of different RE mineral collectors} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: Exploratory investigation of different RE mineral collectors}\label{App_A}
\chaptermark{Exploratory investigation of different RE mineral collectors}
        \input{Sections/AppendixA}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `\LARGE` does not have an argument, it is a font size switch macro. On - Topic: Your example does not compile since we don't have the files that are included with `\input`

Comment: `Bold` and `TexShade` are no regular class options

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `titlesec`. Note it's simpler to have `numbered` chapters in appendix, and let the system number it automatically:

```
\documentclass[12pt,Bold,a4paper,TexShade,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page,title,header]{appendix}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Conclusions, contributions to original knowledge and future work]{\LARGE{Conclusions, contributions to original knowledge and future work}}
\chaptermark{Conclusions, contributions to knowledge and future work}
    % \input{Sections/Conclusions}
\lipsum[1-5]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\huge\appendixname~\thechapter}{2ex}{\LARGE}
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Exploratory investigation of different RE mineral collectors}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]